# What is wrong with this Regex "^(.|\s){1,280}$"

Tags: asp.net, regex

Should be validating 1-280 input characters, but it hangs when more than 280 characters are input.

**Clarification**
I am using the above regex to validate the length of input string to be 280 characters maximum.
I am using asp:RegularExpressionValidator to do that.

Comment: More than 280 is not between 1 and 280 inclusive.

Comment: How big is the input? Can you be more specific about "hangs"?

Comment: @Gumbo that's not the point - rather than just failing, it's hanging, i.e. taking an inordinately long time.

Comment: is there *really* not a strlength() function in ASP????

Comment: @Spudley - of course there is :)  String.Length

Comment: Try this instead: `^(>[\s\S]{1,280})$`.

Comment: @Moo - hehe, yeah. it was a rhetorical question. The real question is why isn't he using it?

Comment: @spudley In this instance, I was using client-side validation plus the Regex validator. Of course I could have employed other options, but thats what we've got here

Comment: All you're doing is counting the length of input string and checking it's >1 and <=280. Using regex is way overkill. In particular since . or (.|\s) or [.\s] will match every character anyway. So all it's doing is counting characters. Just use your String.Length function, already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing “wrong” with it *per se*, but it's horrendous because with most RE engines (you don't say which one you're using) when it doesn't match with the first thing it tries because it causes the engine to backtrack and try loads of different possibilities (none of which can ever cause a match). So it's not a hang, but rather just a machine that's trying to execute around 2<sup>280</sup> operations to see if there's a match possible. Excuse me if I don't wait around for that!

Of course, it's theoretically possible for the RE compiler to merge the `(.|\s)` part of the RE into something it doesn't need to backtrack to deal with. Some RE engines do this (typically the more automata-theoretic ones) but many don't (the stack-based ones).

Comment: The key to the merging is whether the engine can recognize `.` and `\s` as both being character sets and merge them into a single set. If it can, the RE becomes trivial to match in guaranteed-linear time.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to re-write the regex to optmise it then?

Comment: @JAngwenyi: In the engine I use, I'd do `^[\u0000-\uffff]{1,280}$` except that I wouldn't do it that way at all (and the engine has limits on counting too; there are other cases that are much nastier!) Can you really not use something other than an RE to do this validation?

Comment: Yep, I can write a simple JavaScript function to do the validation. It is good to know/understand why this regex was "hanging". Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It is trying every possible combination of `.` and `\s` for each character trying to find a version of the pattern that matches the string.

`.` already matches any character, so `(.|\s)` is redundant. Further, if you just want to check what the length of the string is, then **just do that** - why are you pulling out regexes?

Comment: `.` by default won't match newline.

Comment: @codaddict exaclty! that why I combined both (.|\s), but it seems to hang when evaluating

Comment: K, I was using asp:RegularExpressionValidator to display warning message on client side

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use a regular expression, you could use `.{1, 280}$` combined with the `SingleLine` option, so that the `.` metacharacter will match everything, including new lines (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx#regexnet_topic6), Regular Expression API section).